# What is the relationship between Jasper Reports and Spring MVC versions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

a close friend of mine will soon be teaching some colleagues about Java Jasper Reports and he was wondering why its correct working depends on the version of Spring MVC?

I looked around for an answer but my google skills either aren't where they should be or it hasn't been asked, because all I  found were specific questions on using the libraries.

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jasper reports is just a reporting java library, that's all.
It doesn't matter your spring mvc version, you only have to be safe calling your xml template sending your query results.

regards